# Sorting JSON array with nulls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, knockout.js

My JSON array

```
var jData = [
{id: 1, parent: null},
{id: 2, parent: null},
{id: 3, parent: 1},
{id: 4, parent: 2},
{id: 5, parent: 2},
{id: 6, parent: 1}];
```

I want this be to sorted like the following ( by id then by the parent )

```
[
    {id: 1, parent: null},
    {id: 3, parent: 1},
    {id: 6, parent: 1}
    {id: 2, parent: null},    
    {id: 4, parent: 2},
    {id: 5, parent: 2},
];
```

What is the best way to do it in JavaScript?

I tried, but no luck

```
jData .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id ||a.parent- b.parent);
```

Help!!

Comment: Expected sorting logic is not clear

Comment: @Emil your expected result not looks like sorted by id then by the parent

Answer (score 2):

You need a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) first and then take the nodes in order of appearance.

```js
function getData(array) {
    return array.flatMap(({ data, children = [] }) => [data, ...getData(children)]);
}

var data = [{ id: 1, parent: null }, { id: 2, parent: null }, { id: 3, parent: 1 }, { id: 4, parent: 2 }, { id: 5, parent: 2 }, { id: 6, parent: 1 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(data => {
            Object.assign(t[data.id] = t[data.id] || {}, { data });
            t[data.parent] = t[data.parent] || {};
            t[data.parent].children = t[data.parent].children || [];
            t[data.parent].children.push(t[data.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, null),
    result = getData(tree);

console.log(result);
console.log(tree); // just to show what's happening
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is he trying to achieve?

Comment: ohh its binary tree.

Answer (score 2):

If parent is null we use the id as parent value and sort by parent first (otherwise we won't reach your result). If the parent value comparison results in zero, we sort by id.

```js
var jData = [{id:5,parent:2},{id:1,parent:null},{id:4,parent:2},{id:2,parent:null},{id:3,parent:1},{id:6,parent:1}];

let res = jData.sort((a,b) => {
  let ap = a.parent ? a.parent : a.id,
      bp = b.parent ? b.parent : b.id;
  return ap - bp || a.id - b.id;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to group each array to its parent. Use `0` if parent is null. Use another `reduce` to contruct the final array.

```js
var jData = [{"id":1,"parent":null},{"id":2,"parent":null},{"id":3,"parent":1},{"id":4,"parent":2},{"id":5,"parent":2},{"id":6,"parent":1}]

var temp = jData.reduce((c, v) => {
  let p = v.parent || 0;
  c[p] = c[p] || [];
  c[p].push(v);
  return c;
}, {});

var newjData = temp[0].reduce((c, v) => {
  var o = temp[v.id] || [];
  o.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id); //Sort. Incase the IDs are not in order in the original array.
  c.push(v, ...o);
  return c;
}, []);


console.log(newjData);
```